# What's the name of this kind of matrix in which entries in each column and row are distinct?

Tags: matrices

I want to generate an n by n matrix, in which each column and each row contains each of n letters (or integers if you prefer) exactly once. This is like a sudoku board but without the $3\times 3$ boxes restriction. What is the name for such a matrix?

I want to know this because I want to generate such $26\times 26$ matrices on a computer to play around with some cryptography stuff. (If there is already a method to generate these I would love to see it!)

Comment: It's called a Latin square.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for responding in under a minute!

Comment: Do you know how to generate such size latin squares? I found a website that does it but I would love to know how to program it on my home computer.

Comment: @FarazMasroor, what language?

Comment: I think you should investigate the number of Latin squares of size $n$ before continuing. Huge. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_square#Number

Comment: @jameselmore java